# how do we get separate report in sonarqube 6.5+

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration

We would like to get unit tests and integration tests reported separately in sonarqube 6.+. currently, it shows full tests coverage.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, SonarQube does accept coverage data from multiple sources, and it then **merges** them.

You should use your individual test/coverage tools to further distinguish between different types of coverage.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas B.  running only unit tests at every commit and integration tests at branch merge will cause a skewed graph in SONAR due to it overriding the previous coverage statistics?

Comment: Potentially indeed. Better pass latest coverage data you've got (from each source) for any analysis.

Comment: Another user put up a comment: *We have two reports one for unit test coverage and other for integration test coverage. I have given -DsonarProjectName='Demo' in the command for integration tests, it creates a project in sonar with the name provided, but if we run unit tests then it will override the projectName and the coverage value. Can you please provide me the parameter which is responsible for creating the project in the sonar?*